# Get id of specific element not the parent element

Tags: jquery

I want to get the id of specific element on click, but the problem is that the if the element doesn't have an id, then the function still in a loop for all element's parents that have an ID!!

here's an example, how can I make it alert only for once for specific element?

http://jsfiddle.net/RUadJ/1/

Comment: Which element's id do you want? Do you want the ID of the clicked element?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you've attached your click handler to *every* element on the page, and click events *bubble*. That is, when you click on a child element its click handler will be called, and then its parent's click handler will be called, and so forth. You can stop the event from bubbling using the [`.stopPropagation()` method](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) as follows:

```
$("*").click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();

   // your other code here
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RUadJ/6/

(Or just return `false` from your click handler.)

Alternatively you can compare the [`event.target` property](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) to `this` - if they are the same you know you are processing the "original" click event before it bubbles. (If they are different you know the event has already bubbled.)

P.S. Attaching your click handler to every element is terribly inefficient. You can just attach a single handler to the `document` and then `event.target` (mentioned above) will be the original element clicked on so you can still test its id. Then you don't have to worry about bubbling because the click has already bubbled as far as it can:

```
$(document).click(function(e){
   if($(e.target).attr("id")!= null)
      alert("have id ");
   else
      alert("doesn't have id ");
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RUadJ/26/

Answer (score 1):

[This example](http://jsfiddle.net/RUadJ/13/) will only alert if the element that was directly clicked has an ID.

Without knowing more about what you're trying to achieve, it is hard to offer a better answer.

```
$("*").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    if($(this).attr("id") != null){
        alert("have id ");
    }
});
```

Comment: If you call `.stopPropagation()` (which you've misspelled, by the way) then you don't need to test the `e.target` because the event won't ever bubble past the target - so you can just use `this` as per the original version of the code.

Comment: @nnnnnn: Thankyou, I've updated the answer with your corrections.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the function "loops" is because the event is bubbling up the DOM. To stop the bubbling up, add this code to the top of your handler:

```
e.cancelBubble = true;
if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the * symbol. Try something more specific for example img or a class

```
$("*").click(function(e)....
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the Javascript event bubbling.
The click event will pop up and if you want to stop it, just add the following code:

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

after if-else sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Well in this case you can target specific class

```
$("div.foo").click(function(e){

if(!$(this).attr("id")==''){
    alert("have id ");
}
    else
    {
            alert("doesn't have id ");
    }
});
```

Comment: If you target a specific id to attach the handler then you already know that the element has an id when the handler runs don't you? (Unless ids are being dynamically removed _after_ assigning handlers.)

Answer (score 0):

The selector * is inefficient because it retells all again, it will show you 2 * (elements) loops

```
$("*").click(function(e){
    var elementCount = $("#parent").find("*").length;
    $("body").prepend("<h3>" + elementCount + " elements found</h3>");
});
```